# Resizing Checkboxes in Windows Universal Application

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have crowded Page in my project and I want to place too many Checkbox control in a single page, so I'm looking for a way to resize my **checkboxes**.
When I change height and width of my checkbox, some part of its text disappear, In other word I need to scale my checkbox and make some tiny checkbox.

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you checked out the [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299114.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of the `CheckBox`? They have a min width of `120`.

Comment: I know, but I need a tiny checkbox...what is the solution?

Comment: Is it for a Phone?  Because then your users also need tiny fingers.

Comment: This is a symptom of a bad UI design. You shouldn't need this, look for other solutions.

Comment: No, its not for phone application, It is an Application which runs on a Raspberry pi, so I need to change control size

Comment: "... on a Raspberry pi", so they will need even smaller fingers then.

Comment: Tiny? How tiny? How does it look like? You need to improve your question. An image would be helpful.

Comment: It is a special device and I need to scale down my control, It is impossible to list here all of my constraints and needs.

Comment: I want to just scale down it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can of course scale it down by using `ScaleTransform` but modifying its style gives you more flexibility.

Here's an example -

```
<Style x:Key="TinyCheckBoxStyle"
               TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="4,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="11" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <!-- Add default visual states back in here -->
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle"
                                           Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillUnchecked}"
                                           Height="12"
                                           Stroke="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckBackgroundStrokeUnchecked}"
                                           StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}"
                                           UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                           Width="12" />
                                <FontIcon x:Name="CheckGlyph"
                                          Foreground="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckGlyphForegroundUnchecked}"
                                          FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                          FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                          Glyph="&#xE001;"
                                          Opacity="0" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              Grid.Column="1"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Basically, you need to reduce the size of `NormalRectangle`, `CheckGlyph` and the `FontSize`. Note I have removed the visual states to simplify the answer, you just need to add them back from the [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299114.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: That was exactly what I want, I'm sorry that I did not ask the question properly.

Comment: No worries. That's why there's an Edit button for questions. :)

Comment: @JustinXL thanks very nice. How do I learn how to do the same with say a `ComboBox`?  I tried..